# How to configure Quartz to handle cycles, periods and intervals

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, jobs

I am writing a monitor for my Java backend and need to be able to monitor different things (memory, CPU, user activity, load, etc.) at different times. Most importantly is that I need to be able to configure each monitor (`MemoryMonitorJob`, `CpuMonitorJob`, `ActivityMonitorJob`, etc.) to have the following characteristics:

- Turn on/off in periodic cycles (such as once every 15 minutes)
- To configure how long it stays on for once it turns on (for instance, 2 minutes)
- Thus, I would like to configure, say, the `MemoryMonitorJob` to kick on every 15 minutes, stay on for 2 minutes, and then shut off...**but without that 2 minute interval offsetting the time until the next run!**

Hence, under this specific example, the monitor would exhibit the following behavior:

1. t = 0, turn on
2. 0 < t < 2, run
3. t = 2, turn off
4. t = 15, turn on
5. 15 < t < 17, run
6. t = 17, turn off
7. t = 30, turn on
8. ...

Obviously, somewhere in the configuration code, I need to check that the "interval" doesn't meet or exceed the "period/cycle" time, otherwise we'd have a job attempting to kick off while it was still running!

I believe that the [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) is the right tool for the job here, but I've only used it in the past for setting up simple cron jobs ("*run X every 15 minutes*"). This interval property is throwing me off and after scrupulously looking at the Quartz `CronTriggerImpl` docs I can't seem to figure out how to configure a Quartz job to behave like this.

Ideally, if Quartz can handle this kind of behavior, then I'd just configure 1 monitor `Job` implementation with the correct period/interval settings, and then add them to a Scheduler.

Can Quartz handle this? If so, how (can I see an example?!?)? If not, what are my options here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you define what you mean with "turn on"? Do you mean that it will be a Job that can run for more than 2 minutes, or that it will be doing the same thing over and over for 2 minutes?

Comment: Good point :-) By "turn on", code flow will enter an "infinite" `while(true) {...}` loop and continue to do the same thing over and over again until the "interval" (i.e., 2 minutes) is over. Sorry I didn't clarify that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Quartz triggers work exactly the way you want:

```
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
    .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
        .withIntervalInMinutes(15)
        .repeatForever())
    .forJob(memoryMonitorJob)
    .build();
```

This will fire `MemoryMonitorJob` exactly every 15 minutes, no matter how long your job runs. Of course it's up to you to keep your job class running for two minutes (sleeping, looping, etc.)

If your job runs for more than 15 minutes, you have two options:

- by default Quartz will fire the same job again, overlapping the previous execution.
- if your job is stateful, Quartz won't trigger the job again, waiting for the previous one to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several options here, but the easiest would be to just run the job every 15 minutes using the CronTrigger and than keeping track of the 2 minutes inside the Job.

Job Code

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    Date now = new Date();
    Date inTwoMinutes = new Date(now.getTime() + 2*60*1000);
    while(inTwoMinutes.before(now)) {
        // do something
        now = new Date();
    }
}
```

Scheduling Code

```
job = newJob(MyJob.class)
    .withIdentity("job", "group")
    .build();

trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger", "group")
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 15 * * * ?"))
    .build();

sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

This will trigger the job every 15 minutes.

Another option would be to trigger the same job every second in minute 15 and 16. In that case you wouldn't need the while loop. However, the downside would be that it is harder to keep a state inbetween jobs. The trigger would look like this.

```
trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger", "group")
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule("* 15,16 * * * ?"))
    .build();
```

For more information on triggers:
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger